Why do browsers make two socket connections when requesting a web page?
I make a socket and have it listen for connections, and accept them. When I use a browser to request a page that's being served by my server, I get the following logs that show when accept() has a new TCP connection, one right after the other instantly:
Server logger[VERBOSE_INFO] Received TCP connection from
Address: 49.183.117.125
Port: 20351
Server logger[VERBOSE_INFO] TLS handshake succeeded
    
Server logger[VERBOSE_INFO] Received TCP connection from
Address: 49.183.117.125
Port: 20352
Server logger[VERBOSE_INFO] TLS handshake succeeded

I've tried this with Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, and I've tried it both using the loopback interface, and using my mobile phone so that the packet came from the internet.
Why is this?
I really doubt it's an issue with my code. I'm using the C++ ASIO socket library.
There are always two different socket connections made, even when serving just a simple .html page, so that the browser doesn't make any further requests for .css or Javascript. And the ports are always sequential.
